# Efficient way to display 40+ animated spinning wheels

Tags: html, css

The user can upload 40 files via drag and drop. The designer wants a spinning wheel for each item. I'm using css animation, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to reduce rendering work for the browser.

CSS

```
@keyframes spinning {
 0% {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

Comment: What is telling you that it is not efficient enough? Modern browsers should be pretty good at such simple things.

Comment: Ok, but I noticed that an ipad is running hot while doing so many animations

Comment: Personal opinion, but I guess that has more to do with the device itself and/or the actual upload process that is going on in the background while the animation is being played. If 40 simple icons are too much to handle for a device in 2017 that's by itself problematic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Balázs said, `transform` properties are efficient and there is not that much you can do to smoothen things.

Here is a summary coming from others Stackoverflow posts (links at bottom, of course):

1. Use the `will-change` property ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change))
2. Use Chrome DevTools frame mode to see what is happening on your page and what you could get rid of

You may want to take a look at these references :

- [Improving CSS3 transition performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643240/improving-css3-transition-performance)
- [High Performance Animations - HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)
- [Smooth as butter: Achieving 60 FPS Animations with CSS3](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108)